# Deployment from Azure web site from GitLab

Tags: azure, gitlab, azure-web-app-service, azure-deployment

I followed [this article](https://christianliebel.com/2016/05/auto-deploying-to-azure-app-services-from-gitlab/) to auto deploy my GitLab master branch to Azure.    Under the "Deployment" section in the Azure portal, I selected "Deployment options" -> "Choose Source", which presents these 3 options.

1. Local Git Repository
2. GitHub
3. Bitbucket

There is no "External Repository" option as the article suggests, so dead end there. I thought perhaps I could accomplish this via the Azure CLI instead.  I fumbled by way through the help screens and arrived at this command:

```
az webapp deployment source config --slot stage -u [MY_GITLAB_PROJECT_URL] --branch master --resource-group [MY_GROUP] --name [MY_PROJET_NAME]
```

The command errors with:  "The parameter [MY_GITLAB_PROJECT_URL] has an invalid value".   I tried the SSH url, the HTTPS url (with the .git suffix) and the URL to the repo.  No dice.

Any suggestions?  Im on the free trial plan, if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason why you are not seeing "External Repository" is that you have a linux based app and that feature is not there for linux based apps.

[image: Linux CI/CD]

However if your app were a windows based app, you would see external repositories as an option:

[image: Windows CI/CD]

You can put in a feature request for this here: 
 https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169385-web-apps-formerly-websites

Comment: Thanks Byron for the info.  I posted my feature request here:
https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169385-web-apps/suggestions/31431157-give-linux-web-apps-same-deployment-options-as-win

Comment: `The reason why you are not seeing "External Repository" is that you have a linux based app and that feature is not there for linux based apps.` is really a good information. Many docs are not suited and it's hard to understand why -- without this information. Btw: The feature request mentioned in comment above was declined.